# how to remove letter from one list to the other randomly but to the right location

Tags: python, list, indexing

I just started to learn python and as part of my learning i am trying to make simple programs.

so i tried to make an hangman game and i am stuck.

i cant think of a better way to identify the letter in the word the player need to guess - - and adding the letter at the right place in var of what the player guess so far.

The code:

```
import random

list_of_words = ["door", "house", "work", "trip", "plane", "sky", "line", "song", "ever","life"]

random_word = list_of_words[random.randint(0, len(list_of_words) - 1)]


guessed_word = "_" * len(random_word)

print("Hello!, welcom to my hangman Game")

print("try to guess what word could that be??? ")

print(guessed_word)

guessed_word = guessed_word.split()

random_word = list(random_word)

print(random_word, guessed_word)



while len(random_word) != 0:

    letter = input("guess a letter >>>... ")

    if letter in random_word:

        print(f"YAY! thats right, {letter} is in the word")

        index = random_word.index(letter)

        random_word.remove(letter)

        guessed_word[index] = letter

        print("this is your word now >> ", guessed_word)

    else:

        print("the word isnt there")

print("yay, you found the word")
```

So, the code is running good and it identify when the player finished choosing all the right letters. the problem is how to copy the word and show players progress. so at the start it puts the letter in the right place, but after that it doesn't change the letter location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things wrong here.

- finding only one occurrence of the letter (`door` would only find the first o)
- Removing items loses track of the index
- `guessed_word` splitted wrong

These issues fixed:

```py
import random

list_of_words = ["door", "house", "work", "trip", "plane", "sky", "line", "song", "ever","life"]

random_word = list_of_words[random.randint(0, len(list_of_words) - 1)]


guessed_word = "_" * len(random_word)

print("Hello!, welcom to my hangman Game")

print("try to guess what word could that be??? ")


# Convert to list first
guessed_word = list(guessed_word)
# Print separated with spaces second
print(' '.join(guessed_word))

random_word = list(random_word)

# Check if the guessed word is the same as the random word, if it is, the word is fully guessed
while random_word != guessed_word:

    letter = input("guess a letter >>>... ")

    if letter in random_word:

        print(f"YAY! thats right, {letter} is in the word")

        # find all indices of the letter
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(random_word) if x == letter] # * see notes
        # Update all indices of the guessed word with the letter
        for i in indices:
            guessed_word[i] = letter
        # Don't remove the letter from the random word

        # Print with spaces, because it's nicer that way!
        print("this is your word now >> ", ' '.join(guessed_word))

    else:

        print("the word isnt there")

print("yay, you found the word")
```

Hope this helped! Have fun using python!

*Notes:*

List comprehension can be scary, have a look at [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

```py
guessed_word = guessed_word.split()
```

with:

```py
guessed_word = list(guessed_word)
```

and the reason why on example:

```py
>>> x="work"
>>> x.split()
['work']
>>> list(x)
['w', 'o', 'r', 'k']
>>>
```

`x.split()` splits sentence per white space as a delimiter - you want to split it letter by letter instead.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer nut the problem is still not fixed -YAY! thats right, s is in the word
this is your word now >>  ['s', '_', '_']
guess a letter >>>... k
YAY! thats right, k is in the word
this is your word now >>  ['k', '_', '_']
guess a letter >>>... y
YAY! thats right, y is in the word
this is your word now >>  ['y', '_', '_']
yay, you found the word
out of loop.